# How can i setup a signalr server in my c# app with a reactjs frontend?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am new to all this signalr . I have a app that uses a reactjs frontend and c# backend. I need to start up a signalr server that accepts messages and broadcasts the messages . So basically when i start the app. the signalr server will start. I can send it messages and read the messages from my reactjs frontend and display to the user .
How can i do this , is there an example of this ?

just starting with this

Comment: Is this what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: It would be nicer, if you could share your initial architecture and where you are exactly struggling, so that it would be easier to assist you.

Comment: What kind of application you are using? its asp.net core app? Or windows form or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a app that uses a reactjs frontend and c# backend. I need to
> start up a signalr server that accepts messages and broadcasts the
> messages . So basically when i start the app. the signalr server will
> start. I can send it messages and read the messages from my reactjs
> frontend and display to the user . How can i do this?

It would be nicer, if you could ask specific question along with your current implementation rather asking too generic query.

However, in order to set up a SignalR server in your asp.net core  app with a ReactJS frontend,

First of all, you should install SignalR and need to create a Hub class in your asp.net core project (Called hub service),

After that, configure services and map the hub endpoint in your program.cs class file.

On the React side, you should install the client and should build a connection, so that it should start and listen for messages from your broadcast hum, and invoke server methods to send messages.

Let's have a look in practice how we can implement that:

Assuming your backend is in asp.net core of XXX version as you have react frontend.

So, we can do as following:

SingnalR with Asp.net core:

First of all, install SignalR package with your project according to project version:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`

[image]

You can even use nuget package manager:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`

Hub Class:

In this step, you should create a hub class which will communicate with your client/React/javascript frontend.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
```

Register SignalR in Program.cs:

```
using SignalRChat.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");

app.Run();
```

Frontend-React or Javascript:

Within the react or javascript side, you should install following npm package:

`npm install @microsoft/signalr` and need to `Import HubConnectionBuilder` and finally, need to create a connection.

You can do as following:

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@microsoft/signalr';

const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:5000/chatHub') 
    .build();
```

**Note:** Make sure you have updated your hub URL accordingly.

Connected with the hub:

```
connection.start()
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to SignalR hub'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error connecting to hub:', err));

connection.on('ReceiveMessage', message => {
    console.log('Received message:', message);
    
});
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Within the `connection.on` you can display the message in your React component or anything you want. If you need any further assistance on this, [please refer to this official document for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). In addition, you can also [checkout this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/signalr/javascript-client/samples/6.x/SignalRChat/Program.cs) as well.

Comment: and how to i automatically start up the signalr server ? Does it start when the app starts ?

Comment: Register signalr : it is in Startup.,cs not Program.cs ?

Comment: Yeah it will start autometically. Above asp.net core 6 within `program.cs` and below it should be `startup.cs`

Comment: the section Register SignalR in Program.cs:. I dont have a similar program.cs fiule .. its the Startup.cs file and when i put  app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");, it says iapplicationbuilder  does not contain a definition of MapHub and the best extension method overload HubEnpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHub<ChatHub>

Comment: also using SignalRChat.Hubs; gives error "the type or namesapce name SignalRChat could not be found"

Comment: Well, the goal of my answer was to guide you how you should proceed. So now you aret trying to integrate that within your application, and you have specific error or queryies regarding your issue. Thus, with your existing code and issue, it would be nice if you can post new question, therefore, it will be easier to assist you. Would you kindly now post new question along with your code, so that it can be investigate accordingly.

Comment: the package microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr has been deprecated ?

Comment: oh ok , yeh i will do that ...

Comment: Based on your application version you have to choose right package. What kind of app you are working on? Have you register `endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");`

Comment: where do i do that .. as i said i am new to this ...

Comment: Don't worry, post your new question, with your existing code, I will guide, what kind of application you are working on? asp.net core which version?