SignalR fails at negotiation request: Error: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports
While trying to initializing a new HubConnectionBuilder on my react app, I get the following Development console messages/errors:

The app has a react frontend and a c# .net 8.0 backend.
React Code - uses @microsoft/signalr 8.0.0 library
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from "@microsoft/signalr";
let signalRConn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:5003/signalr/derphub", "longPolling")
      .configureLogging("Trace")
      .build();

signalRConn
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log("Connected to SignalR hub"))
      .catch((err) => console.error("Error connecting to hub:", err));

signalRConn.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
      console.log("Received message:", message);
    });


a proxy is used, which could be the cause of the problem, but is unknown
const createProxyMiddleware = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const { env } = require("process");

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
  ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}`
  : env.ASPNETCORE_URLS
  ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(";")[0]
  : "http://localhost:49594";

const context = ["/derp/**", "/signalr/**"];

module.exports = function (app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    ws: true,
    headers: {
      Connection: "Keep-Alive",
    },
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};

C# project.cs Code uses library: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
// rest of project code
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapHub<DerphubRHub>("/signalr/derphub");

C# DerpHub.cs code (it's run in a background service):
 public class DerpHub : Hub
 {
     public async Task SendMessage(string message)
     {
         await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
     }
 }

I've used this stack answer as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77804213/1829773
Other things I've tried:

turning on the ISS websocket feature (through the control pannel)
switching between transport types
panicking

How can i get this to work?

If you're using the JavaScript client, try setting the transport type in the net 8 program.cs file like so: app.MapHub("/signlar/derphub", o => { o.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets; }); Use WebSockets only, and remove the "longpolling" transport in the client. If using only WebSockets doesn't work, try not setting the transport type at all.

Another issue may be your sticky sessions. If you're not using a load balancer, your JavaScript client has to skip the negotiation step.

I'm running this on a local machine.  Do i need sticky sessions for that? I tried changing the .net program file, the error messages only mention the WebSocket failing, but is still similar in that no connection can be made.

After removing out the transport type, I did get a succesfull connection while using the ServerSentEvents protocol

You can skip it if you're running locally.
